# Execute POST request in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, http-post

I have a simple Wordpress API for likes inside of my iOS App. And I get this JSON : `{"status":true,"num_likes":2}`.

What I do want to have happened, is to when the user clicks the button, it sends `POST` request to server and the server automatically increases  `num_likes`, so I do not have to worry about it. Just, how to I send that simple request?

How do I do it in Swift?

link for API: http://sekaaleksic.cloudlk.com/api/v1/post/{post_id}/like/{user_ip}

link for countLikes: http://sekaaleksic.cloudlk.com/api/v1/post/1/countLikes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS:

1. Create a `NSURLRequest`

   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://yourendpoint")!)
2. Set method to `POST`

   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
3. Send it

   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
   task.resume()

#### Final code:

```
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: "http://yourendpoint")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        task.resume()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I answered the question about how to sens a POST request. Then you just have to use string interpolation or concatenation on the NSURL constructor string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$site/posts/$post_ID/likes/new")!

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    if let response = response, data = data {
        print(response)
        print(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

where $site is your site ID or domain, and $post_ID is the post's ID.